# Time out when connecting to Redshift from AWS EC2 using psycopg2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I'm working on a simple **Python** program to query a Redshift cluster using *psycopg2*. When I run the code on my local machine it works as expected: it creates the connection, it runs the queries and I get the expected outcome. However, I loaded it on my EC2 instance because I want to schedule several runs a week and the execution fails with the following error:

> **psycopg2.OperationalError:** could not connect to server: Connection timed out
>           Is the server running on host "xxxx" and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5439?

Considering that the code is working without problems on the local machine and the security settings should be the same as EC2, do you have any suggestions and/or workarounds?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Most probably, It's firewall i.e. `ACL` issue on `Redshift` and `EC2` side.

Comment: make sure your ec2 instance is in your security group for redshift.

Comment: @JonScott I'm trying to connect to a Redshift cluster that I don't own so I can't check/edit security group rules for it. However, I have access through login and password so I can connect using DataGrip and/or running the same python program from my local machine.

Comment: Well there is your problem, you need to request that the ip address or security group of your ec2 instance is added to the security group for the redshift cluster you are trying to access.